# Align two div next to each other and third div under them

Tags: html, css

How do I place two div's side by side and the third one below them? Like this:

[image]

My Current code is like below:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="div-1">div1</div>
    <div class="div-2">div2</div>
    <div class="div-3">div3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
     position: absolute;
}

.div-1 {
     float: left;
     width: 45%;
     padding: 2%;
}

.div-2 {
     clear: both;
}

.div-3 {
     float: right;
     width: 45%;
     padding: 2%;
}
```

Comment: What's the result of your coding currently?

Comment: @ott - right now I'm having large space on top of div3. I tried reducing that gap using margin-top but it breaks as the content of div3 changes.

Comment: Why not just change the ordering of your divs so that the second div breaks correctly to the next line i.e. http://jsfiddle.net/661bgfsy/

Comment: You can do it with absolute positioning if you can have fixed heights... but you probably don't want that. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jsa2g7y1/

Answer (score 4):

You can use **Flexbox**

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#container div {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px; 
}

.div-1, .div-3 {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

.div-2 {
   flex: 100%;
   order: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="div-1">Div 1</div>
    <div class="div-2">Div 2</div>
    <div class="div-3">Div 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it works well but is it achievable without flexbox too?

Comment: Well if you want elements in that order `1, 3, 2` i think flexbox is by far best solution. If not then i suggest that you use bootstrap to get that layout and it will be responsive.